# What is wrong with this drag-n-drop javascript code?

Tags: javascript, html

It took me like 3 hours to solve this but i still don't know what exactly caused such behaviour.
i am trying to write a browser game where you have inventory and equipment tab.
When i move item divs from inventory to equipment tab divs it all works but as soon as i try to move it back to inventory all items get stacked on mouse cursor.
I solved it by moving equipment inventory div to be child of equipment-tab div.
but i am still not sure what caused that problem. i hope i explained it well.
I have this HTML code

```
<div id="equipmenttab" >
  <div class="leftitems">
    <div  class="dragcontainer" id="helm" ></div>
    <div  class="dragcontainer" id="neck"></div>
    <div  class="dragcontainer" id="shoulder"></div>
    <div  class="dragcontainer" id="cape"></div>
    <div  class="dragcontainer" id="chest"></div>
    <div  class="dragcontainer" id=""></div>
    <div  class="dragcontainer" id=""></div>
    <div  class="dragcontainer" id="wrist"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="rightitems">
    <div  class="dragcontainer" id="glove"></div>
    <div  class="dragcontainer" id="waist"></div>
    <div  class="dragcontainer" id="legs"></div>
    <div  class="dragcontainer" id="feet"></div>
    <div  class="dragcontainer" id="ring"></div>
    <div  class="dragcontainer" id="ring"></div>
    <div  class="dragcontainer" id="trinket"></div>
    <div  class="dragcontainer" id="trinket"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottomitems">
    <div  class="dragcontainer" id="mainhand"></div>
    <div  class="dragcontainer" id="offhand"></div>
    <div  class="dragcontainer" id="wand"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="inventory-container">
  <div  class="dragcontainer inventory" ><div id="12" class="item helm" 
                                              draggable="true"></div></div>
  <div  class="dragcontainer inventory" ><div id="13" class="item 
    chest" draggable="true"></div></div>
  <div  class="dragcontainer inventory" ><div id="156" class="item 
    legs" draggable="true"></div></div>
  <div  class="dragcontainer inventory" ></div>
  <div  class="dragcontainer inventory" ></div>
  <div  class="dragcontainer inventory" ></div>
  <div  class="dragcontainer inventory" ></div>
  <div  class="dragcontainer inventory" ></div>
  <div  class="dragcontainer inventory" ></div>
  <div  class="dragcontainer inventory" ></div>
</div>
```

and this javascript code

```
var draggeditem;
var items = document.getElementsByClassName("item");
for (i=0;i < items.length; i++){
  items[i].addEventListener("dragstart", function(){
    draggeditem=event.target.id;
    //event.dataTransfer.setData("text", event.target.id);
    draggedItemClassName = event.target.className;
    draggedItemClassName = draggedItemClassName.split(" ");
    console.log(event.dataTransfer.getData('text'));  
  });
}    

var containers = document.getElementsByClassName('dragcontainer');
for (i=0; i < containers.length; i++) {
  containers[i].addEventListener("drop", function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    if(hoveredItemId == draggedItemClassName[1]){
      event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(draggeditem));
      draggeditem = null;
      console.log(draggeditem);
    }
    else if(hoveredItemClassName[1] == 'inventory'){
      event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(draggeditem));
      draggeditem = null;
      console.log(draggeditem);
    }
  });
  containers[i].addEventListener("dragover", function(){
    hoveredItemId = event.target.id;
    hoveredItemClassName = event.target.className;
    hoveredItemClassName = hoveredItemClassName.split(" ");
    console.log(hoveredItemClassName[1]);
    event.preventDefault(); 
  });
}
```

Comment: does this code work as expected or is there a problem with it? it's unclear from your question as you state that you solved your problem!

Comment: Since your issue solved, why did you post this here ?

Comment: This code doesnt work as expected and i posted it because i hope someone can explain why did it happen.

Comment: @JirkaKastan Can you post your CSS as well so we can run your code as a snippet?

Comment: Sorry i just switched off laptot and i am on mobile now so i cant post CSS.

Comment: @JirkaKastan Nothing we can do to help you then as your CSS most likely contributed to the issue you're describing.